# Sending Python Request While On VPN

Tags: python, curl, request, vpn

I am attempting to send a get-request to a url that returns a dataset; however, it only works when I am *not* on the company VPN (GlobalProtect). Whenever I send the request over the VPN, I receive the following error: "('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))" I believe that this error is caused when the VPN gets rejected by the target server but I am not certain. A previous version of this script, which was a curl script, also did not work on the VPN. Any fixes? Here is the code:

```
# import modules required for the ETL process, including parameters
import requests
import datetime
import shutil
import csv
import sys
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from pypac import PACSession
from curlParameters import *

# calculates year for use in the parametarized file name
def calculate_year():
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    return str(current_year)

# creates the file name using name, year, and file type
def file_name():
    name = "CallDetail"
    year = calculate_year()
    file_type = ".csv"
    return name + year + file_type

session = PACSession()
session.get(url)

# sends get-request using parameters and basic authorization; prints in case of error
try:
    response = requests.get(url, params=parameters, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

except Exception as e:
    print("Error: " + str(e))
    sys.exit()

# probes for 200 status code to ensure successful request
if response.status_code == 200:
    # parses response into CSV-readable format and writes it to CSV file; prints in case of error
    try:
        raw_data = response.text
        parsed_data = csv.reader(raw_data.splitlines(), delimiter=delimiter)
        with open(local_source+file_name(),"w", newline='', encoding=encoding) as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=delimiter)
            writer.writerows(parsed_data)

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: " + str(e))
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: If it works fine without the VPN, but doesn't with the VPN, then I'm not sure there's anything to do in the code.  It's going to be up to your VPN provider if it's blocking certain ports, or if the server doesn't like something about the data coming out of it. Maybe you could change some ports around if you figure out the root cause, but I don't see how we could ascertain the root cause from your source.

Comment: Can you access the website behind your vpn in browser?

Comment: @0x263A Yes, I can access the website while on the VPN but not through the script.

Comment: Then it likely isn't the vpn causing the issue directly.

Comment: @0x263A Any possible ideas?

Comment: @Owen Im having the same issue here, did you find a workaround this?

Comment: @monti I did not find a workaround yet but believe that the issue is being caused by the target website denying the request to protect itself. I imagine that asking the company to accept the request from my company's VPN would work, but I did not find it worth the while to ask. What issue are you having?

Comment: @Owen, I am getting the same error for a POST request (posting from my local to remote) but this same POST request works when I try it with the curl cmd. I have also tried other POST requests but from a remote to another remote and it works. couldn't tell what is the problem here.

Comment: @monti I would ask one of your systems admins to help, if possible. Regardless, it is really hard to pin down exactly what is causing the issue. Does the remote server require a certain format for the POST request, or is there any issue with the firewall or something? I am not sure.

Comment: @monti I think that I know another possible cause. All our systems have "service accounts," which are essentially emails/Windows accounts assigned to a program (like SQL Server, UiPath, etc.) that can be given explicit permissions to send requests or interact with the browser or even other programs. The solution would be to create a service account, but I am not sure whether they would approve it. So, I do not know if it will work for sure. Maybe try it on your end?